# ESP32-CAM OV2640 AS A SUN SENSOR

Tags: esp32-cam

I want to use the ESP32-CAM as a sun sensor, the problem is that I would need to remove the lenses in order to put a membrane with a pinhole (like it's illustrated in the image) upon the CMOS, but I want to know first, will this make unoperable the OV2640? I want it to be working fine without the lenses, the second image is an illustrative of what I want to do.
[image: Fig.1]

[image: Fig.2]

Comment: what is preventing you from determining the results experimentally?

Comment: It is a bit expensive here in Mexico, 227.00 pesos (13.14 USD), so I only have one shot to buy it, I know It may not be that expensive in other currencies, but here is like a week worth of food haha, so that's why... I dont want anyone to make the experiment and possibly hurt their ESP32-cam, I just would like to know If someone has tried it.

Comment: that is a very good reason for not determining the results experimentally

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? ... what does the sun sensor measure?

Comment: I want to measure the azimuth and elevation angle, thanks to the incident angle of the sun!

Comment: if you know your geographic location and the correct time, then those values can be calculated without the need for a camera

Comment: As an alternative to disassembling the camera, you may consider keeping the lens, and pointing the whole camera to the sun through a high-density neutral density filter. A B&W negative fully fogged and developed may serve as a cheap filter.

Comment: Yes, they can be calculated, but I want to make a sun sensor to use it to simulate an ADCS for a cubesat, this will be a second sun vector, I already have the sun position vector, thru the Vallado algotihm

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the ESP32-CAM as is. Instead use a [pin hole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera) box. Put the ESP32-CAM inside the box pointing it at the image of the sun at the back of the box. This approach mitigates problems associated with exposing the sensor to the elements and direct exposure to sun light.

In order to measure azimuth and elevation, consider mounting the device such that it points directly up from the surface of the earth.  And such that it is aligned to true North. Consider using an accelerometer to detect the device is normal to the surface of the earth. And a magnetometer to detect magnetic north.  And a GPS receiver to detect the position on earth.  Combine the GPS data with  [World Magnetic Model (WMM) data](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml) to correct for magnetic declination.

Comment: Yeah!! I thought of that, but I think that the aperture diameter of the camera already kinda serves as a pinhole, what I want to do is to have oportunity to make it myself so I will have the possibility of control the values that I want, like the FoV for example.

Comment: Unless you find someone who has done this, you are asking for opinions which stack exchange is not equipped to handle.  You added that you need azimuth and elevation. You will need to add a tilt compass in order to get azimuth and elevation. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: That is a good idea, Im going to consider it, thanks!!

Comment: I am not sure how you would do this, but I believe that a [SHARP distance measurement sensor](https://www.adafruit.com/product/164) has a linear optical sensor.  So it may be possible to modify 2 of these to measure the angle of the sun along the north south axis and along the east west axis.  Again, not sure how you would do this.  But these sensors my be less expensive to experiment with.